# Wordpress пагинация

Tags: wordpress, пагинация

the_posts_pagination() не выводит пагинацию на странице категорий кастомных записей. На архивной странице кастомных записей все работает. Помогите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`the_posts_pagination()` работает только с главным циклом WordPress. На странице категорий у вас, скорее всего, свой цикл ( `WP_Query()` или `get_posts()` ). Это и является источником проблемы. Обойти эту проблему можно только таким хаком (выдержка из рабочего кода):

```
global $post, $wp_query;

$query_args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' =>  get_query_var( 'page' ),
    // и прочее...
);

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // вывод поста
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = null;
    $wp_query   = $query;

    the_posts_pagination();

    // Reset main query object.
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $temp_query;
}
```

Здесь перед вызовом `the_posts_pagination()` мы подменяем глобальную переменную главного цикла WordPress на наш цикл, а потом возвращаем назад.

Comment: У меня данный цикл работает только на странице главной, а на странице категорий нет. Пагинация выводится, но при переключение страниц перекидывает просто на дефолтный шаблон

Comment: @Alan.Sh здравствуйте, вы решили как-то эту проблему?

Comment: Спасибо! Работает! С помощью этого метода удалось вывести пагинацию и заменить ее на ajax бесконечную загрузку товаров топ продаж и т.д. которые выведены простым циклом в шаблоне главной страницы.