# Почему пагинация не работает внутри шорткода?

Tags: wordpress

Мне нужно вывести посты с помощью шорткода в определенном месте

```
// Посты пользователя
add_shortcode ('test','fan');   
function fan(){
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
else $paged = 1;    
$html.='<div class="gt">'; 
$args = array(
  'paged' => $paged,   
  'posts_per_page' =>  5,    
  'post_type' => 'post'  
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) { 
  while( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {    $custom_query->the_post();
// Блоки новостей
get_template_part( 'news', get_post_format() );
}  
$html.='</div>';
 if ($custom_query->max_num_pages > 1) {  
      $orig_query = $wp_query;
      $wp_query = $custom_query;
    $html.='<div class="pagination">';
 }  
     the_posts_pagination(array(      
        'prev_text' => ('←'),  
        'next_text' => ('→'),  
        'end_size'  => 1, 
        'mid_size'  => 2  
      ));   
        $html.='</div>';
 }  
  $wp_query = $orig_query;  

  }
  wp_reset_postdata();  
 }  else {
   get_template_part( '404', get_post_format() ); 
  $html.='</div>';
 }  

$html.='</div>';
return $html ;
}
```

Но почему-то внутри него все работает нормально, кроме пагинаций.
Она почему-то не выводится. В чем может быть причина и как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что пагинация работает только в главном цикле WordPress. См. мой ответ с хаком, позволяющим это обойти: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944878/220220

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ на свой вопрос
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430392/wordpress-pagination-in-a-shortcode

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');
else $paged = 1;

$q = new WP_Query(  array ( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'post', order => 'ASC', 'paged' => $paged  ) );

$list = ' ';

while ( $q->have_posts() ) { $q->the_post();
  $list .= '<div class="listing-view clearfix">'. get_the_title() . '</div>';
}

  $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
echo paginate_links( array(
   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
   'format' => '?paged=%#%',
   'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
   'total' => $q->max_num_pages //$q is your custom query
 ) );

wp_reset_query();

return 
'<div class="listings clearfix">' 
. $list 
. '<div class="nav-previous">' . next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'stratford_wp' ) ) . '</div>'
. '<div class="nav-next">' . previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'stratford_wp' ) ) . '</div>'
. '</div>';
```