# Не выводится пагинация WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть следующий код, но почему-то нумерация страниц вообще не выводится, не могу понять в чем причина.

```php
<div class=" blog-content">
    <?php wp_reset_query(); $query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => '4', 'category__not_in' => '7', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ?: 1)); ?>
    <?php if( $query->have_posts()){ while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="content-box">
            <div class="blog-img-frame">
                <a class="blog-img" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                   <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(386, 290)); ?>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                   <h4 class="blog-text-uppercase"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                </a>
                <p class="block-date"><?php the_author(); ?> - <?php echo get_the_date('j F Y'); ?></p>

                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <div class="blog-buttons">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">read more
                    <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } /* конец while */ ?>
<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
<?php } wp_reset_query(); // конец if ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Пагинация не работает вне главного цикла WordPress. Где-то в моих ответах я давал хак, поищу ссылку.

Comment: Поищите, пожалуйста, очень нужно

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944878/220220