# Некорректная работа пагинации Wordpress — не отображаются посты на следующей странице, как исправить?

Tags: wordpress

Объясните пожалуйста по шагам, как реализовать постраничную навигацию в шаблоне вывода постов, без использования плагинов?

В месте, где нужно вывести пагинацию, использовал такие варианты:

1) `<?php echo get_the_posts_pagination(); ?>`

2) `<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>`

Разницы между ними не заметил. (А она по идее должна быть). Обе эти функции создают ссылки пагинации, но проблема в том, что при переходе на следующую страницу с новостями, все равно отображаются новости с первой страницы. Перехожу на третью страницу - тоже самое, показывает новости с первой страницы, хотя УРЛ меняется на /page/2, /page/3/ и т.д.

В настройках чтения указал выводить 6 постов на странице. Постов имеется больше, чем 6, если что. Так что, проблема не в том, что у меня просто не хватает постов для корректного отображения.

Как правильно настроить пагинацию? Нужно ли прописывать что-то в functions.php?
Прошу по возможности дать максимально подробный ответ.

Вот полный код шаблона вывода постов. Может в нём что-то не так?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blogpost page
Template Post Type: page
*/ 
?>

<?php get_header('subsub'); ?>

  <div id="company-news-section">
    <div class="content-container">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="home-page-title">
              <h1><?php wp_title("", true); ?></h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <?php query_posts("cat=7"); ?>  
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <div class="container">
          <div class="row news-spacing">

              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                  <div class="news-preview-img">
                    <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                  </div>        
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="news-date">
                  <p><?php the_time('j F Y') ?></p>
                </div>

                <div class="news-txt-part">
                  <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                  <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </div>  
              </div>

          </div>    


      </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="pagi-block">
          <?php echo get_the_posts_pagination(); ?>
        </div>  
      </div>        


    </div>  
  </div>    

</section>
```

Comment: "А она по идее должна быть" - не должна. код посмотрите. `the_posts_pagination` состоит из одной строки: "echo get_posts_pagination()".

Comment: Никогда не используйте в своём коде `query_posts` - это функция для ядра. Надо использовать `get_posts` или `WP_Query`.

Comment: Решение здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944837/wordpress-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f/944878#944878

Comment: Читаю то, что вы скинули и чувствую, что ответ рядом. Проштудировал инфу по get_posts() и WP_Query, вроде как основные принципы понял, но не могу синтаксически верно оформить это, так как пока не хватает знаний в пхп.

Был бы вам очень признателен, если бы вы смогли исходя из моего частного случая, помочь правильно составить цикл для вывода постов определенной категории с дальнейшим выводом пагинации.

Т.е., на сколько я понял, мне нужно взять обычный WP цикл и модернизировать его используя get_posts или WP_Query, но опять же, у меня пока не выходит.