# Почему не отображается пагинация вордпресс?

Tags: php, wordpress

Почему не отображается пагинация ВП?

Почему `<?php echo get_the_posts_pagination(); ?>` не работает (не отображается пагинация) при использовании стандартного цикла ВП `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?> <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>`

Есть код шаблона:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Analytics page 
Template Post Type: page
*/ 
?>

<?php get_header('subsub'); ?>
<div id="analytics-post-section">
    <div class="content-container">


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="analytics-page-title">
                        <h1><?php wp_title("", true); ?></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-7 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="analytics-item">
                        <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="analytics-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?> 
                </div>

                <?php get_sidebar() ?>

            </div>  
        </div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="pagi-block">
                    <?php echo get_the_posts_pagination(); ?>
                </div>  
            </div>



    </div>  
</div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Почему-то вот этот кусок не отрабатывает `<?php echo get_the_posts_pagination(); ?>` и пагинация не отображается на странице. Why?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Некорректная работа пагинации Wordpress — не отображаются посты на следующей странице, как исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1023440/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-wordpress-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80)

Comment: Не надо дублировать вопросы

Comment: Прочитайте внимательнее оба вопроса, они отличаются первоначальными условиями. Этот вопрос идет про стандартный цикл вордпресс, а тот, что по ссылке - про query_posts

Comment: Напишите это явно в вопросах, тогда к вам не будет таких претензий

Comment: Написал это явно в вопросе своем. Надеюсь теперь претензий нет :)

Comment: Теперь претензий нет )