# Не работает wp pagenavi на странице категорий

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, pagination, wp-plugin

Всем доброго дня, не могу настроить пагинация постов на странице категорий, пагинация выводится но при клике на любую страницу открывается дефолтный шаблон. Пол дня провозился не пойму в чем проблема, раньше всегда работало

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="post_page archive">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="post_content">
          <div class="breadcrumbs">
              <?php the_breadcrumb(); ?>    
          </div>  

          <h3 class="page-post_title"><?php echo single_cat_title() ?></h3>
<div>
<?php
  $count_items = 2;//кол-во выводимых элементов
  $paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );//Получаем текущую страницу
  $id = get_category_by_slug( 'xabarta' )->cat_ID;//получаем id рубрики.рубрика новости.
  $recent = new WP_Query( "cat=$id&posts_per_page=$count_items&paged=$paged" );//Сам запрос
  while ( $recent->have_posts() ) {
    $recent->the_post();
    ?>

          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="single_post">
              <p class="date_publish">Сегодня| 21:40</p>
              <p class="title_post"><?php the_title(); ?></p>  
          </a>
<?php
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>    
<?php
  wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $recent ) );//вывод пагинации.

?>
</div>    
        </div> 
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да что же такое, уже каждый первый вопрос об этом. Посмотрите предыдущий вопрос с меткой WordPress. Вот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944837/wordpress-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f/944878#944878

Comment: Данный способ тоже не работает, при переключении кнопок пагинации открывается дефолтный шаблон

Comment: Код рабочий, с одного из моих сайтов. Значит, ошибка у вас где-то ещё.

Comment: На главной странице все работает, а вот на странице рубрики нет