# Криво работает пагинация в WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, пагинация

Всем добрейшего времени! Подскажите кто чем может. Вывожу пагинацию на странице с превью новостей, пагинация работает, почти все как надо, кроме одного НО, нажимая на 1 страницу, мне нужно что бы меня возвращало на mysite/news, а он меня кидает на mysite/news/page/1/, полагаю проблема кроется где то тут, 
str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),но не могу найти решение, буду благодарен за подсказку! 
Вот кусок кода

```
  <?php
                $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                //описание настроек:https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links
                $pagination_args = array(
                    'base'               => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                    'format'             => '%#%',
                    'total'              => $custom_query->max_num_pages,
                    'current'            => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                    'show_all'           => false,
                    'end_size'           => 0,
                    'mid_size'           => 2,
                    'prev_next'          => true,
                    'prev_text'          => __(''),
                    'next_text'          => __('Дальше'),
                    'type'               => 'plain',
                    'add_args'           => false,
                    'add_fragment'       => '',
                    'before_page_number' => '',
                    'after_page_number'  => ''
                ); ?>

                <div class="navigation pagination list_items_pag" role="navigation">
                    <div class="nav-links">
                        <?php
                         //if (function_exists("pagination")) {pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages);} 
                            echo paginate_links ($pagination_args);
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944878/220220

Comment: Добавил свой код для наглядности

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать через if | else. Если ID страницы 1, то переадресовываем пользователя на 'mysite/news/'.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно пагинацию перед выводом обернуть в функцию preg_replace:

```
$pagination = paginate_links ($pagination_args);
$pagination = preg_replace( '~/page/1/?([\'"])~', '\1', $pagination );
echo $pagination;
```