# wordpress infinite scroll не работает на произвольных страницах

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Я использую плагин [WP EasyScroll Posts](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-infinite-scroll-posts/) для динамической подгрузки новостей (cсоздал свой custom type - news) при скролинге в ленте на странице архива. Код ниже.

```
  <div class="container cp2 news-list scroll">
<div class="list">
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args=array_merge(array( 
        'post_type' => 'news', 
        'posts_per_page' => 10, 
        'paged'=>$paged,
        'orderby'=>['date' =>'DESC'])
    ,$args);
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); // запрос к БД
    if($wp_query->have_posts()):
    while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : // запускаем цикл
    $wp_query->the_post(); 
     ?>
        <a class="item" href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>">
            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'large')?>" alt="">
            <div class="caption"><?php the_title();?> </div>
        </a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
<?php the_posts_pagination(['total'=>$wp_query->max_num_pages]); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
</div>
```

И всё прекрасно работает. Но если использовать этот же код на произвольной странице (созданной в админке), то динамическая подгрузка новых данных не происходит.

Вот скриншот настроек плагина.
[image: скиншот]

Я что-то делаю не так? Или в WP в принципе нельзя реализовать такое на страницах которые не являются архивом?

ВНИМАНИЕ! Пагинация выводится.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944878/220220

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Wordpress пагинация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944837/wordpress-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Нет. Пагинация выводится нормально.

Comment: Может лучше обратиться в поддержку плагина?

Comment: Его перестали поддерживать. так что думаю вопрос в целом не актуален уже. Буду искать другой плагин

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью этой статьи: [ссылка](http://gnatkovsky.com.ua/beskonechnaya-prokrutka-postov-wordpress-bez-plagina.html).
И немного переделал под себя