# Вывод пагинации на статической странице WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Имеется следующий код:

```html
<?php
$args=array(
'showposts'=>100, //сколько показать статей
'cat' =>-126,
'cat' =>-1330, 
'orderby'=>modified, //сортировка по дате
'caller_get_posts'=>1);
$my_query = new wp_query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
$my_query->the_post();
?>
<?php
     get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    ?>
<?php } }
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Показывает на статической странице 100 последних обновлённых записей.

Как можно разбить эти 100 записей на несколько страниц?

**UPD**

Скомпоновал свой код с кодом, предложенным KAGG Design https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944878/363550 способом.

```html
<?php
global $post, $wp_query;

$query_args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3, // Количество постов на странице
'cat' =>-126,
'cat' =>-1330, 
'orderby'=>modified, //сортировка по дате
'caller_get_posts'=>1);

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
 ?>
 <?php       
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
     ?>
<?php }}
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = null;
    $wp_query   = $query;

   the_posts_pagination();

    // Reset main query object.
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $temp_query;
?>
```

Всё работает, но не меняются посты на страницах - на всех три последних измененных поста. Хотя URL, title, description страниц меняется.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно как то так

```html
<?php
  $args=array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3, // Количество постов на странице
    'showposts'=>100, //сколько показать статей
    'cat' =>-126,
    'cat' =>-1330, 
    'orderby'=>modified, //сортировка по дате
    'caller_get_posts'=>1
  );
  $my_query = new wp_query($args);
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
      $my_query->the_post;
      get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    }
  }
  the_posts_pagination(array('showposts'=>100));
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Так работать не будет. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944878/220220

Comment: В 500 ошибку уходит.

Comment: @Skanex я набросал из того чтобы были и предположил) 
попробуйте использовать комментарий выше

Comment: @Yamich да, я понимаю))) Спасибо! Просто уже бьюсь с этим второй день.

Comment: @Skanex исправил потерял ";" )) попробуй

Comment: @KAGGDesign, по вашему методу работает, но записи не обновляются при постраничном переходе. Поправил вопрос с примером кода. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: @Skanex забыл в своём ответе по ссылке добавить строку `'paged' =>  get_query_var( 'page' ),`. Поправил ответ.