# Как сделать пагинацию при выводе товаров?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как сделать разделение на страницы при выводе товаров? Есть цикл в котором я вывожу товары, но если их будет много нужна пагинация, подскажите как это сделать? Я находил стандартные шорткоды woocommerce, но я так понял что они мне не подойдут. Вот код страницы с выводом

```
<?php get_header();?>

    <div class="content container">

    <?php get_sidebar('cat'); ?> 
    <!-- <?php
        $sort=$_GET['product_cat'];
        echo do_shortcode('[products limit=»2″ columns=»4″ orderby=»popularity» class=»quick-sale» on_sale=»true» category="'.$sort.'" ]');
    ?> -->

        <div class="products-main">
            <?php  $loop = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'product',  // указываем, что выводить нужно именно товары
            'posts_per_page' => 12, // количество товаров для отображения
            'orderby' => 'date', // тип сортировки (в данном случае по дате)
            'product_cat' => $sort,
            )); 



            while ( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="product-main">
                <div class="product-img"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="avatar"><img class="responsive-img" src="<?php
                $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
                echo $thumb_url[0];
                ?>" alt=""></a>
                <div class="product-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                <div class="product-size">Размер: <?php echo $product->get_attribute('size'); ?> см.</div>
                <div class="product-price__box">
                    <div class="product-price">Цена: <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> грн.</div>
                    <div class="info-cart"><a><img src="/wp-content/themes/dropship/assets/img/cart.png"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-button">
                    <button class="fast-buy">Быстрая покупка</button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>

    </div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: На большинство вопросов ответы уже есть на StackOverflow https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944837/wordpress-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f/944878#944878

Comment: @KAGGDesign подскажите как именно вы ставите количество товаров, не совсем понял Ваш код

Comment: @KAGGDesign у меня не срабатывает код, могу я задать ещё один вопрос?