# Как исправить пагинацию wocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть код вывода товаров, сделал по ответу одного из учасников, например по 2 товара на странице, далее я хочу сделать пагинацию, но пагинация не срабатывает, сам код появляется и видно 1 2 3 Далее, но при нажатии просто на главную бросает, как это можно исправить, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
global $post, $wp_query;

$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',  // указываем, что выводить нужно именно товары
    'posts_per_page' => 2, // количество товаров для отображения
    'orderby' => 'date', // тип сортировки (в данном случае по дате)
    'product_cat' => $sort,
);

$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        ?>
                    <div class="product-main">
                <div class="product-img"> <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="avatar"><img class="responsive-img" src="<?php
                $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
                echo $thumb_url[0];
                ?>" alt=""></a>

                </div>
                <div class="product-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                <div class="product-id"><?php echo $product->get_id() ?></div>
                <div class="product-size">Размер: <?php echo $product->get_attribute('size'); ?> см.</div>
                <div class="product-price__box">
                    <div class="product-price">Цена: <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?> грн.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="product-art">Артикул: <?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?></div>
                <div class="product-button">
                    <button class="fast-buy-green"><a onclick="tobasket(<?php echo $product->get_id();?>)">В корзину</a></button>
                    <button class="fast-buy">Быстрая покупка</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $temp_query = $wp_query;
    $wp_query   = null;
    $wp_query   = $query;

    the_posts_pagination();

    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $temp_query;
};?>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Wordpress пагинация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944837/wordpress-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @Krya код смотрел там, но у меня другая ошибка, которая не входит в тот вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать еще раз, у вас такая же ошибка

Comment: @Krya извините, возможно я не понимаю, но у меня ошибка такая как в коментарии человека под ответом, возможно подскажете как можно это исправить?

Comment: Используйте paginate_links вместо the_posts_pagination. the_posts_pagination работает только на главный цикл wordpress. А у вас в примере кастомный WP_Query.

Comment: @Krya добавил, но ничего не изменилось, может я что-то не так сделал?

Comment: Посмотрите пример в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `paginate_links` вместо `the_posts_pagination`. `the_posts_pagination` работает только на главный цикл wordpress. А у вас в примере кастомный WP_Query.

```
global $paged;
$paged = max( $paged, 1 );
$per_page = 10;
$total = ceil( $query->found_posts / $paged );
$args = array(
    'total'        => 1,
    'current'      => $paged,
); 

echo paginate_links( $args );
```

Comment: Добавил этот код, не сработало. Количество страниц считается правильно, но не изменятся товары. Что может быть не так?

Comment: в $query_args добавьте 'paged' => max( 1, $query->paged ),

Comment: пагинация сама по себе не работает же)

Comment: как можно это исправить, я добавил в $query_args, но ничего не изменилось(

Comment: подскажите что может быть не так?

Comment: /?paged=2&page_id=5 вот такая ссылка получается, но переход не происходит

Comment: Добавьте параметры base, format в paginate_links

Comment: и проверьте возвращает ли $query->paged текущую страницу

Comment: $query->paged ничего не возвращает, в чём проблема? Я сделал echo $query->paged; ничего не вывелось