# Ошибка 404 при переходе с пагинации

Tags: php, wordpress

Это очень распространенная ошибка. У меня проблема заключается в том, что один и тот же код пагинации, работает корректно на архивной странице archive-blog.php, но выдает 404 ошибку при переходе на вторую страницу записей на странице категории, используя шаблон archive.php (category.php тоже выдает ошибку ). Очень прошу помочь сообщество. Перепробовал кучу разных вариантов и ни один не заработал.

### archive-blog.php (Здесь работает)

```
<?php
/**
 * The template archive pages
 */

get_header( 'blog' );
?>

<main class="bg-white" style="margin-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="breadcrumbs" typeof="BreadcrumbList" vocab="https://schema.org/">
            <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
            {
                bcn_display();
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="title-classic col-12">
                <h2 class="h-text-heading text-center unselectable"><?php echo "Наш блог" ?></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="grid-container">
                    <?php
                        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
                        $idx = 1;
                        $args = [
              'post_type' => ['post', 'blog'],
                            'posts_per_page' => 7,
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'order' => 'DESC',
                            'orderby' => 'date'
                        ];

                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

              $post_id = get_the_ID();
                            $thumb_size = 'thumbnail';
                            $thumb_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, $thumb_size );
                    ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="<?php echo "post-$idx "; if ( 4/$idx === 4 ) echo "focus-post" ?> blog-card-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <img class="blog-card-item__thumb" src="<?php echo $thumb_url ?>" alt="">
              <p class="blog-card-item__title text-center unselectable"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            </a>
                    <?php $idx++ ?>
                    <?php
                            endwhile;
                    ?>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                <?php 
                $big = 999999999; // уникальное число

                echo paginate_links( array(
                    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
                    'type' => 'list'
        ) );
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

### archive.php / category.php (Здесь выдает 404)

```
<?php
/**
 * The template archive pages
 */

get_header( 'blog' );
?>

<main class="bg-white" style="margin-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="breadcrumbs" typeof="BreadcrumbList" vocab="https://schema.org/">
            <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
            {
                bcn_display();
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="title-classic col-12">
                <h2 class="h-text-heading text-center unselectable"><?php single_cat_title()?></h2>
                <p class="p-text-heading text-center unselectable"><?php category_description() ?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="grid-container">
          <?php
                        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
                        $idx = 1;
                        $args = [
                            'post_type' => ['post', 'blog'],
              'posts_per_page' => 7,
                            'paged' => $paged,
                            'order' => 'DESC',
                            'orderby' => 'date'
                        ];

                        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

              $post_id = get_the_ID();
                            $thumb_size = 'thumbnail';
                            $thumb_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, $thumb_size );
                    ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="<?php echo "post-$idx "; if ( 4/$idx === 4 ) echo "focus-post" ?> blog-card-item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <img class="blog-card-item__thumb" src="<?php echo $thumb_url ?>" alt="">
              <p class="blog-card-item__title text-center unselectable"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
            </a>
                    <?php $idx++ ?>
                    <?php
                        endwhile;
                    ?>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                <?php 
                $big = 999999999; // уникальное число

                echo paginate_links( array(
                  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                  'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                  'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
                  'type' => 'list'
                // ) );
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Этот вопрос задают очень часто. Вот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944878/220220

Comment: Попробуйте погуглить

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Wordpress пагинация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/944837/wordpress-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)