# Вывод постов одной категории с пагинацией на кастомную страницу

Tags: wordpress, post

Всего 6 постов в категории, выводит на одну страницу 5 постов, т.е. всего в пагинации будет 2 страницы (2 ссылки). Все отображает правильно на первой странице, но при нажатии на вторую страницу пагинации выдается первая, а не вторая, как должно быть. Буду очень признателен за ответ.

```
<div class="news__archive">
    <?php $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts('category_name=news&showposts=5&paged=$page'); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="news__single">
        <div class="news__single_wrap df">
            <!-- image -->
            <?php hellpa_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <div class="news__single_text">
                <!-- link on full text -->
                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Читать далее"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                <!-- date text -->
                <p class="news__single_date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
                <!-- short text -->
                <div class="news__single_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Читать далее</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php echo get_the_posts_pagination(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944878/220220

Comment: И перестаньте использовать query_posts, он для ядра. Для создания своих циклов есть get_posts и WP_Query

Comment: Спасибо за ответ KAGG Design - все решил по другому.

Comment: Слушай, есть отличная статья на эту тему https://wp-punk.com/ne-zabujte-s-vashej-paginatsiej/